# How do I find the cause of an EC2 autoscaling group "health check" failure? (no load balancer involved)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The EC2 instances in my AWS autoscaling group all terminate after 1-4 hours hours of running.  The exact time varies, but when it happens, the entire group goes down within minutes of each other.

The scaling history description for each is simply:

> At 2016-08-26T05:21:04Z an instance was taken out of service in response to a EC2 health check indicating it has been terminated or stopped.

But I haven't added any health checks.  And the EC2 status checks all pass for the life of the instance.

How do I determine what this "health check" failure actually means?

Most questions around ASG termination all lead back to the load balancer, but I have no load balancer.  This cluster processes batch jobs, and  min/max/desired values are controlled by software based on workload backlog elsewhere in the system.

The ASG history does not indicate a scale-in event, AND the instances are also all protected from scale-in explicitly.

I tried setting the health check grace period to 20 hours to see if that at least leaves the instance up so I can inspect it, but they all still terminate.

The instances are running an ECS AMI, and ECS is running a single task, started at bootup, in a container.  The logs from that task look normal, and things seem to be running happily until a few minutes before the instance vanishes.

The task is CPU intensive, but error occurs still when I just have it sleep for six hours.

Comment: By default, without an ELB, the ASG will only use instance status checks. However the actual message you are getting "an instance was taken out of service in response to a EC2 health check indicating it has been terminated or stopped" sounds more like the OS on the instance shutdown or somebody (or some process) initiated a stop or terminate command. Are these spot instances?

Comment: They are spot instances.  Many of these _are_ listed as terminated by price!  I didn't think to check the spot requests given the message.  Is this normally how a spot price termination appears in the ASG history?

Comment: @mark-b yeah all of my "health check" failures correlate with the spot price terminations.  If you can re-post your answer I'll flag it as correct.

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 9):

Here are few suggestions:

- To see why instance was terminated, in EC2's *Instance* list select *terminated* instance, and select *Get System Log* in *Instance Settings* (menu), then scroll down to the bottom to see any obvious issues. The logs are kept for a while after instance is terminated.
- In ECS cluster within your active service, check *Events* tab for any messages.
- In *Target Group* section, verify *Health checks* and *Targets* (*Registered targets* and their *Status*, and *Health* of the *Availability Zones*.

  To modify health check settings for a target group using the AWS Console, choose *Target Groups*, and edit *Health checks*.
- In ASG (EC2's *Auto Scaling group*), check *Details* (for *Termination Policies*), *Activity History* (for termination messages), *Instances* (for their *Health Status*), *Scheduled Actions* and *Scaling Policies*.
- Check *CloudWatch* for any available logs.
- Check *CloudTrail* for any suspicious events.
- Verify that ECS agents are connected: [Why is my Amazon ECS agent listed as disconnected?](https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-agent-disconnected/)
- Check also: [Health Checks for Your Target Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-health-checks.html) and [Amazon ECS Troubleshooting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting.html).
- For more suggestions, check: [terraform-ecs. Registered container instance is showing 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46578949/55075)

Answer (score 4):

By default, without an ELB, the ASG will only use instance status checks. However the actual message you are getting "an instance was taken out of service in response to a EC2 health check indicating it has been terminated or stopped" sounds more like the OS on the instance shutdown or somebody (or some process) initiated a stop or terminate command. Are these spot instances? This is what you will see if spot instances are terminated.

Comment: can we find the actual reason for the same. I have a higher spot bidding price when the instance was terminated. Probably, there were no instances present in the region. But can we find the exact information somewhere?