# terraform-ecs. Registered container instance is showing 0

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs

On running `terraform apply` it is creating a cluster, service, ec2 instance. But Registered container instances is 0, running tasks count is 0.

I tried changing `ecs.amazonaws.com` to `ec2.amazonaws.com` but it is throwing an error:

> aws_ecs_service.nginx: InvalidParameterException: Unable to assume role and validate the listeners configured on your load balancer. Please verify that the ECS service role being passed has the proper permissions.

[image]

```
    provider "aws" {
        region = "us-east-1"
    }

    resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "demo" {
      name = "demo"
    }

    resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_elb" {
        name = "ecs-elb"
        assume_role_policy = <<EOF
    {
      "Version": "2008-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "ecs.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
      ]
    }
    EOF
    }

    resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "ecs_elb" {
        name = "ecs_elb"
        roles = ["${aws_iam_role.ecs_elb.id}"]
        policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole"
    }

    resource "aws_launch_configuration" "ecs_instance"{
        name_prefix = "ecs-instance-"
        instance_type = "t2.micro"
        image_id = "ami-4fffc834"
    }

    resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ecs_cluster_instances"{
        availability_zones = ["us-east-1a"]
        name = "ecs-cluster-instances"
        min_size = 1
        max_size = 1
        launch_configuration = "${aws_launch_configuration.ecs_instance.name}"
    }

    resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "nginx" {
      family = "nginx"
      container_definitions = <<EOF
      [{
        "name": "nginx",
        "image": "nginx",
        "cpu": 1024,
        "memory": 768,
        "essential": true,
        "portMappings": [{"containerPort":80, "hostPort":80}]
      }]
      EOF
    }

    resource "aws_ecs_service" "nginx" {
        name = "nginx"
        cluster = "${aws_ecs_cluster.demo.id}"
        task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.nginx.arn}"
        desired_count = 1
        iam_role = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_elb.arn}"
        load_balancer {
            elb_name = "${aws_elb.nginx.id}"
            container_name = "nginx"
            container_port = 80
        }
    }
    resource "aws_elb" "nginx" {
        availability_zones = ["us-east-1a"]
        name = "nginx"
        listener {
            lb_port = 80
            lb_protocol = "http"
            instance_port = 80
            instance_protocol = "http"
        }
    }
```

Comment: According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html, the `aws_iam_role` should be `ec2.amazonaws.com`, *not* `ecs.amazonaws.com`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS ECS Error when running task: No Container Instances were found in your cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523282/aws-ecs-error-when-running-task-no-container-instances-were-found-in-your-clust)

Answer (score 4):

Here are few suggestions to check in *AWS Console*:

- Make sure that you are using [Amazon ECS-optimized AMIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html).

  Basically these instances, once you login as `root`, they should have `start ecs` command.

  Terraform example:

  ```
  data "aws_ami" "ecs_ami" {
    most_recent = true
    owners      = ["amazon"]

    filter {
      name   = "name"
      values = ["amzn-ami-*-amazon-ecs-optimized"]
    }
  }
  ```
- Check whether EC2 are spinned up.
- Check your *Load Balancing Target Group* (e.g. why they're not registered by checking [Health status](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-health-checks.html) of the instances in *Targets* tab, *Attributes* in *Description* tab and *Health checks* tab).
- Check whether ECS agent is running on the EC2 instances.

  1. Login to EC2 instance as `root`.
  2. Run `docker ps` and check for whether `ecs-agent` container is running.
  3. Otherwise start manually by `start ecs` or `restart ecs`.

  <sub>Note: If you don't have `docker`, `start` or `restart` command, you're not using ECS-optimized AMI.</sub>
- When the instances get terminated.

  - Verify that ECS agent is still running (check above).
  - When using *Launch Configurations*, check your user data script for errors. Also, that it adds the right cluster to `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` ECS config file. And it starts ECS agent (`start ecs`).
  - Check system logs of terminated instances by navigating to *EC2 Running Instances Dashboard*, selecting terminated instance, *Get System Log* in Instance Settings (menu), then scroll down to the bottom to see any obvious issues. The logs are kept for a while after instance is terminated.
  - Check the ECS logs (`tail -f /var/log/ecs/*`).
  - See: [Why is my Amazon ECS agent listed as disconnected?](https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-agent-disconnected/).
  - Check: [How do I find the cause of an EC2 autoscaling group "health check" failure? (no load balancer involved)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39172639/55075)
- Once instances have *ECS agent* running, make sure you assigned them into the right cluster. E.g.

  ```
  root# cat /etc/ecs/ecs.config
  ECS_CLUSTER=demo
  ```
- Note the *IAM role* of the running EC2 instance, then make sure that [***AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role***](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html) policy is attached to that role.
- In ***Trust relationships*** tab of that cluster role, make sure to give the access to EC2 provider to that role. Example *role trust policy*:

  ```
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  }
  ```

  Terraform example:

  ```
  data "aws_iam_policy_document" "instance" {
    provider = "aws.auto-scale-group"

    statement {
      effect  = "Allow"
      actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

      principals {
        type        = "Service"
        identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  See: [What is the purpose of AssumeRolePolicyDocument in IAM?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/5094/3).

  You also need `aws_iam_instance_profile` and `aws_iam_role`, e.g.

  ```
  resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "instance" {
    provider = "aws.auto-scale-group"
    name     = "myproject-profile-instance"
    role     = "${aws_iam_role.instance.name}"

    lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
    }
  }

  resource "aws_iam_role" "instance" {
    provider           = "aws.auto-scale-group"
    name               = "myproject-role"
    path               = "/"
    assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.instance.json}"

    lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
    }
  }
  ```
- Now, your cluster should be ready to go.

---

Related:

- [AWS ECS Error when running task: No Container Instances were found in your cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36523282/55075)

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshooting ecs problems, you can follow below steps.

1. click service name `nginx`, check if any tasks are in `pending` status. If you see that, normally there are a lot of `stopped` tasks.

That means the containers are not healthy.

2. click service name, events, check if there any error events to help you do the troubleshooting.
3. Click `ECS instances`, if there are any instances in the list. If not, that means no ec2 instance is successfully registered itself to ECS cluster.

If you use AWS ECS AMI, it should be fine. But if you use your own AMI, you need add below userdata script

ecs-userdata.tpl

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "ECS_CLUSTER=${ecs_cluster_name}" >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

update terraform codes:

```
data "template_file" "ecs_user_data" {

  template = "file("ecs-userdata.tpl") }"

  vars {
    ecs_cluster_name = "${var.ecs_cluster_name}"
  }
}


resource "aws_launch_configuration" "demo" {
  ...
  user_data = "${data.template_file.ecs_user_data.rendered}"
  ...
}
```

4. Enable docker container logs, the easiest way is to send the logs to aws cloudwatch.

Add below resource first.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "app_logs" {
  name              = "demo"
  retention_in_days = 14
}
```

Then add below codes into task definition.

```
"logConfiguration": {
  "logDriver": "awslogs",
  "options": {
    "awslogs-group": "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.app_logs.name}",
    "awslogs-region": "${var.region}"
  }
},
```

after you applied change, go to `cloudwatch`, logs to check if there are any error logs.

5. change iam role to  `["ecs.amazonaws.com", "ec2.amazonaws.com"]`

     `"Principal": {
       "Service":  ["ecs.amazonaws.com", "ec2.amazonaws.com"]
     },`

   Hope these steps are helpful for you.

Future reading:

[Launching an Amazon ECS Container Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html)

Comment: No task are in pending/stopped state. Also no logs are generated in cloud watch.

Comment: Event under service : service nginx was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. Reason: No Container Instances were found in your cluster. For more information

Comment: ok, that means no ec2 instances are added to that ecs cluster. Is `ami-4fffc834` belong to AWS ecs image, if you use your own AMI image, you need to customize the `user-data` to add itself to ecs cluster when starting

Comment: I added item 3, let me know if this can fix your issue.

Comment: EC2 instance got created and bootcmd ran successfully:
  - echo ECS_CLUSTER=demo >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config. But no instances under ecs console

Comment: how about item 5?

Comment: Didn't work. No iAM role is present with the EC2 instance